# Editing an SQL Database 

Tags: windows, mysql, xampp, database-administration

I'm new to php, so I installed xampp for windows.

Is there a windows software for easy MySQL administration? 
(creating/displaying/editing tables + data, creating relations ..) 
i've managed to open MySQL databases with ms access but it's a bit tricky.

my 2nd question:
where exactly is the MySQL data stored? is it stored in a physical file which can be deleted/copied like ms access files?
when working with colleagues, I'm finding it a bird hard synchronizing data if someone changes something (the database needs to be exported - imported ..)

Answer (score 1):

first question, [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net) is pretty much the defacto for that setup.
second, with a larger implementation of SQL, its not that simple. The phpmyadmin interface gives you options for backup and reinstatement of your database through the gui, that is how you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have many choice:

1. [Phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) (installed by xampp)
2. [MySQL Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/)
3. [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) (Not Free)
4. [MySQL WorkBench](http://wb.mysql.com/)

Comment: MYSQL Query Browser has reached EOL (End of Life) so now you use the tool within MYSQL workbench, which is pretty darn good. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

One of the best and most oft used Database Management tools is PHPMyAdmin.

PHPMyAdmin has quite a user friendly interface and thus is most popular amongst beginners. PHPMyAdmin provides the users with a feature rich interface that does the work well and is easy to understand and work with.
[Here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php12p2.html) is a great resource to learn the interface for PHPMyAdmin.

Yes. The data for MySQL is stored like any other data on your computer. You can find all the MySQL tables and databases you make in:

C:/xampp/mysql/data

Happy Coding! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use Base application of OpenOffice with its [MySQL connector](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/mysql_connector) plugin.